# Using a transistor instead of a relay to control a DC motor

Tags: transistors, relay, dc-motor

I've made a simple relay circuit to switch power to a small DC motor

Here is a diagram of what I got right now:
[image]

Is it possible to replicate that with a transistor. Which one would be a good choice?

Comment: We'll need to know about the motor.  Is it a brush DC motor?  What is its peak current?

Comment: Its a DC motor, not sure if its brush or not?
Its for a auto winding mechanism in my Airsoft rifles box mag.
So when the trigger is pulled, it will start winding BB's up in the mag, and the 2nd switch is for pre-winding without shooting.

Comment: If you run it by simply applying a voltage to it it will be a brush motor. BLDC (BrushLess DC) motors need a motor controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a logic gate MOSFET, like the FDC855, and then your circuit will look like this:

[image]

A FET will give you a high current if needed (probably not necessary, since you're powering the motor from AA cells).

Or a BJT like the BC547, and then you would make it like this:

[image]

With the 1 kΩ base resistor you'll have minimum 100 mA current for the motor. If you need more I'd recommend the FET solution.
The diode can be a 1N4148.

Comment: Just to be sure. You write 3.7V lipo, it is a 7.4V Lipo? Yeah i know its a bit strange, actaully it started out with a practical problem with the 2 power sources being far apart.
But know i remake it, i could just use the lipo i guess? so i would just use a big resistor between the motor and lipo?

Comment: @Christian - Sorry, I missed that 7.4 V. A LiPo is typically 3.7 V, so yours will be two in series. A series resistor is not a good idea to regulate a voltage down. Suppose the motor draws 1 A, then you would need a (7.4 V-3 V) / 1 A = 4.4 \$\Omega;\$ series resistor to get 3 V, but if the current will drop to 0.5 A, for instance because of no load, then the resistor will only drop 2.2 V, and the motor will get 5.2 V. Granted, this will increase the current again, but it still is a bad way to control a voltage. maybe you can power the motor from one LiPo cell?

Comment: @Christian - Fixed LiPo voltage in schematic

Comment: Well my lipo is one big battery pack. and it powers some other stuff too. so i guess im just sticking with the 2 AA's to power the motor...
Ill just take a look at the schematic and test it out with your suggestions

Comment: @Christian - do you know about *switchers*? They're very efficient voltage regulators, which can downconvert the 7.4 V to the 3 V the motor needs.

Comment: No never heard of those? that would work? even if voltage drop as battery gets drained?

Comment: @Christian - That's the fun of switchers. Linear regulators will lose much power at high input voltages, and may need a few volts more in than out (though LDOs, for Low-Drop-Out don't need as much). But a switcher (you want a **buck converter**) won't dissipate much power, even with 5 V input-output difference, and will keep working until the input voltage is equal to the output; the duty-cycle simply becomes 100 %. There are even types which still will gives you 3 V out when the input drops below that (**buck-boost converters**) but the input probably won't go that low.

Comment: Its a Voltage Regulator right? 
Just watched some video about them, think that would be perfekt :)

Comment: @Christian - Yes, a voltage regulator. They've been discussed extensively here on EE.SE, a search will give you lots of questions and answers about them, how they work, and how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can quite easily.  I'd recommend a Power MOSFET and make sure the power generated by the Ids (motor current) across Rds(on) doesn't exceed the heat handling capabilities of the package.  And make sure that the max current doesn't exceed the Ids(max) as well.

Since you have two push-button switches you can just parallel them up in the new circuit.